# If one line wasn't executed how to execute another?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

```
a = []
b = []

for i in range(3):
   if i == 0:
      a.append('Hi')
   elif i == 1:
      b.append('World')
   else:
      pass
```

if `b.append('World')` wasn't executed how can I append an empty string to b list (`b.append('')`)?

Edit: So, when the for loop begins it starts with 0:

```
if i == 0:
   a.append('Hi')
```

So it appened 'Hi' to the (a) list. So, when it did that, `b.append('World')` wasn't executed. If it (`b.append('World')`) wasn't executed, how can I execute (`b.append('')`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
a = []
b = []

for i in range(3):
   if i == 0:
      a.append('Hi')
   if i == 1:
      b.append('World')
   # When 'World' is not appended, append '' to the list.
   else:
      b.append('')
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be done in the `else` section.

The pattern against each `if` statement is matched, and if none match then the contents of the `else` statement will be called.

If you remove `pass` and replace that with `b.append('')`, you will find it to work.

Enjoy coding :)

Comment: You should probably add the corrected code cample to make it a perfect answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean something like this :

```
a = []
b = []

for i in range(3):
    if i == 0:
        a.append('Hi')

    if i == 1:
        b.append('World')
    else:
        b.append('')
```

the  `if-else` statement does what you want, because the `else` statement refers just to that `if` condition, so when `b.append('World')`  isn't executed it executes `b.append('')`